# How to shard data in couchdb

Tags: database, couchdb, sharding, couchdb-2.0

I just finished setting up a CouchDB cluster with 3 nodes. Now I am trying to shard my data to scale the database, this is what I did to create a database with 2 shards and 2 replicas:

- Create a database with the command

  ```
  $ curl -X PUT "http://username:login@myhost:5984/test?q=2&r=1&w=1&n=2
  ```

  Received a true message.
- Create 50 documents in database "test"

However, When I checked the all three nodes, I found each nodes has a complete copy of all 50 documents. When I deleted one of the documents from node 1, this document got deleted in all three nodes' test database. It seems that cluster works fine but not the way I want.

In my opinion, if I set shards as 2 and replicas as 2, the database will be divided into two parts, each parts will be saved in two nodes. For example, I got a list [1,2,3,4]. I am going to store it in my database just created, it is possible that

The node1 has :

[1,2] [3,4]

The node2 has:

[1,2]

The node3 has:

[3,4]

.

but definitely not [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] [1,2,3,4] respectively in three nodes. Am I right?

If not, why didn't my database partition my 50 documents? My aim is scaling and reliability. It seems that it did not extend my storage at all.

Comment: how did you check that they each have all 50 docs? What does the meta-db entry (host:5986/_dbs/test) report for the chosen layout?